# @Math not rendering in dust.js

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I'm trying to use the @math helper in a dust template to add 1 to a value.  My data looks like:

```
{
    array:[5,10,20]
}
```

My dust template looks like:

```
{#array}
<div class="span2">Amount {@math key="{$idx}" method="add" operand="1"/}:</div>
<div class="span2">{.}</div>{~n}
{/array}
```

This renders everything except for the @math.  I'm using dust-full-1.2.2.js so the math helper is included.  Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: did you copy/paste the code? you have a syntax error `"span2` needs the end quote

Comment: im not sure how that happened, but thats not how it is in my actual code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dust-full-1.2.2.js` does not include any helpers, so that is a part of your problem. The helpers can be found here: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers

The other problem is just a small syntax error. The `@math` helper is self closing, so your code would look like this:

```
<div class="span2">Amount {@math key="{$idx}" method="add" operand="1"/}:</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the difference?